# iTextSharp error : infinite table loop : row content is larger than page

Tags: itext, row, infinite-loop

I'm trying to add content from my database to a table I created with iTextSharp
but I get this error:

```
>infinite table loop : row content is larger than page
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach (string n in Data)
                {
                    PdfPCell cella = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(n.id.ToString()));
                    table.AddCell(cella);
                    PdfPCell cellb = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(n.Valeur));
                    table.AddCell(cellb);
                    PdfPCell cellc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(n.Titre));
                    table.AddCell(cellc);
                }

            table.SpacingAfter = 40f;
            document.Add(table);
```

Its the `n.Valeur` that causing the problem although its content is not that big, mainly a paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

added this settings table and it solved it for me partially

```
table.SplitLate = false; 
table.SplitRows = true;
```

Comment: Didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's happens when the bug object's (n.Valeur) width or height is more than a page (eg:A4).
You must reduce the width or height.

Comment: How to ensure that the height of the row should be less that the height of the page?

Comment: Good question @TejSoft... I'm trying to discover as well